# Django ModelForm never passes is_valid()

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I'm new to Django and I am currently trying to store data entered from a form into a model/database. The bit which I think is causing the issue is that I don't want all the model fields accessible on the form. The model I have has the fields as follows:

```
    description = models.TextField()
    date_referred = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=True)
    column_number = models.IntegerField()
    notes = models.TextField()
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The ModelForm I am using is as follows:

```
class ReferralForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = kanban_item
        fields = ["item_name", "description", "full_name", "email", "phone_number"]
```

The code inside of the views.py file is this:

```
def submit_referrals(request):
    form = ReferralForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReferralForm()
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("VALID")
            referral = form.save(commit=False)
            referral.user = request.user
            referral.column_number = 0
            referral.colour = "ffffff"
            referral.save()
        else :
            print ("NOT VALID")
```

As you can see, I am trying to create a model from the form then add the extra fields and then save the model to the database. This is not working as whenever I submit the form my code never gets past the is_valid method on the form.

Any suggestions or answers are appreciated as I am lost, thanks.

Comment: I noticed that some fields in **models.py** can't be left blank but they are not in your form... this is the Error you'll face after solving this one

Comment: for this issue please instead of `print("NOT VALID")` use `print(form.errors)` to check where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the `ReferralForm` with the data (`request.POST`) and probably also with the files (`request.FILES`).

A `Form` without data is called an "*unbounded*" form, and unbounded forms are always invalid. You thus create a form with data with:

```
def submit_referrals(request):
    form = ReferralForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReferralForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  # 🖘 add data and files
        if form.is_valid():
            print("VALID")
            referral = form.save(commit=False)
            referral.user = request.user
            referral.column_number = 0
            referral.colour = "ffffff"
            referral.save()
        else :
            print ("NOT VALID")
```

Comment: Adding the request.FILES made the form pass, could I ask what data is being passed in this parameter?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArchiePayne: the files that are uploaded when you submit the form: it thus maps input elements to file content, whereas `request.POST` contains data (text, numbers, etc. filled in for the form).